# webpack-dev-server doesn't refresh bundle.js neither watch

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, typescript2.0

I'm building angular2 app with typescript 2.0.
My application run well but I've an issue with webpack bundle and hot reloading.

To create my updated `bundle.js` and to run the `server` for newly created bundle.js, I've to execute 2 commands separately.

`webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`

I want to do it with 1 command only , that's `npm-start` and reload server by having a `watch` for the changes for any file(`html or js`)

for this I've include script in my `package.json` as below :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline"
  },
```

but it doesn't refresh my `bundle.js`.

**Below is my `webpack.config.js` :**

```
var path = require("path");

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "app");
var config = {
    entry: path.resolve(APP_DIR + "/main.ts"),
    output: {
        path: APP_DIR,
        publicPath: APP_DIR,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: "node_modules"
            }
        ]
    }
}
module.exports = config;
```

I've also analysed this [question of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870100/bundle-js-missing-from-webpack-build-when-using-webpack-dev-server) and used the [plugin](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin) mentioned, but getting the error:
`throw new Error('output.path is not. Define output.path.');`, which is defined in config.

Could anyone figureout what's wrong ? and further is it possible to refresh `bundle.js`and watch with single command without `plugin` ?

Comment: Add `-w` (or `--watch`) to the command line of `webpack-dev-server` to have it watch for changes (and rebuild its in-memory version of `bundle.js` when they happen).

Comment: I already tried it also, It does compile the `bundle.js` successfully , `webpack: Compiling...
Hash: ab2ebe01ab340bbc5483
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 6973ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  4.21 MB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 4.09 MB [rendered]
   [23] ./app/app.module.ts 2.31 kB {0} [built]
   [58] ./app/app.component.ts 2.71 kB {0} [built]
     + 365 hidden modules
webpack: Compiled successfully.`   but the webpage doesn't refresh. I have to execute `webpack` again , in order to refresh.

Comment: I assume that you're point your browser to the HTTP server that `webpack-dev-server` provides? Does your browser show anything on console when you made any changes?

Comment: Yes, I'm pointing to same HTTP server, even browser console log updates for every code change, but just `UI doesn't refresh`. Also tried with clearing `cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` does not write any file to disk and it works without having the file present, because it will serve it from memory when the path is hit. If you're testing it without building it first (by running `webpack`), it should still work, if it doesn't, you didn't hit the correct path and get the bundle from your file system.

That is the case here because you've set [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) to the absolute path of your `app` directory. This means `bundle.js` will only be served when you request it as `/full/path/to/app/bundle.js`. What you really want is the bundle being served on `/app/bundle.js`. For this you can change the public path to `/app/`.

```
output: {
    path: APP_DIR,
    publicPath: "/app/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
```